# sumproduct on condition that text strings match

Tags: string, matlab, strcmp

and thank you for showing interest in my post :)

**Let me quickly describe the data I'm working with:**

I'm important data from excel into my matlab script so that I end up with 3 vectors. These are:

- **"FIT_txt"** (~250k rows containing mixed letters & numbers in each cell. repeated entries)
- **"FIT_num"** (same number of rows as "FIT_txt" containing numbers only)
- **"sector"** (~5k rows containing mixed letters & numbers in each cell. unique entries)

**Now, what I want to achieve:**

1. create a vector that counts the number of times each row in "sector" is appearing in "FIT_txt". E.g.: say the first entry in "sector" is "AB10", then I want to create a vector that counts the number of times "AB10" occurs in "FIT_txt"; this should be saved in the first row of the new vector. The second row of the new vector counts the appearances of row 2 from "sector" (say "AB11") in "FIT_txt", etc.
2. create a vector that adds all the numbers in "FIT_num" that occur in the same row as the entries in "FIT_txt" that correspond to a "sector" entry, and sort it accordingly. E.g.: "AB10" in row 1 of "sector" occurs 3 times in "FIT_txt" - it occurs in row 2, 500 & 2000. I want to add up rows 2, 500 & 2000 in "FIT_num" and put them into the first row of the new vector.

Now, this is a simplification of my problem; essentially, I am using a lot more data and I'm repeating this process to find a much larger number of new vectors/matrices. With regard to the simplification, I have managed to solve the problem by doing this:

```
units = zeros(length(sector),1);
installed = zeros(length(sector),1);    

for a = 1:length(sector)
        for z = 1:length(FIT_txt(:,1))

            if strcmp((FIT_txt(z,1)),(sector(a)))==1

                units(a,1) = units(a,1) + 1;
                installed(a,1) = installed(a,1) + FIT_num(z,1);

            end

        end
    end
```

Unfortunately, I fear this is very inefficient and takes way too long to calculate.

I have managed to achieve decent results for my first question (counting the appearances) using this:

```
units = zeros(length(sector),1);

for a = 1:length(sector)
    units(a,1) = sum(strcmp((FIT_txt(:,1)),(sector(a)))
end
```

That works fine (although still taking a bit longer than I would like), however, I don't know how to solve my second question (counting the values from "FIT_num" that correspond).

I would appreciate if you could assist me in finding a solution that is as efficient as possible in solving my problem.

Thank you very much in advance.

John

Comment: can a row from `sector` appear twice per row of `FIT_txt` ? and how should the summation than go? weighted by the number of occurrences or just add or not add? Also, what datatype is FIT_txt, 250x1 cell array?

Comment: Thanks Gunther for your reply. Most rows in "sector" appear multiple times in "FIT_txt". I want to a) count how many times each entry from "sector" appears in "FIT_txt". b) sum all values from "FIT_num" that are on the same rows as "FIT_txt" that correspond to the same entry in "sector". Does that make sense? Sorry I find it a little difficult to express.

Comment: But can one single sector row appear multiple times in one single FIT_txt row? eg, `sector(1) = 'AB10'` and that appears two times on the first row of `FIT_txt`. Should the corresponding value from `FIT_num` now be counted twice?

Comment: Ah. It can only occur once per row. I.e., you would not get something like FIT_txt(1)='AB10AB10', it would contain only "AB10" and hence be entirely identical to sector(1).

Comment: To clarify: "FIT_txt" and "FIT_num" are of the format (x,1) where x is roughly 250000. "sector" has the same format but with considerably fewer rows (~5k).

Comment: *working on it, can you please run `who` in matlab and tell the size and class of FIT_txt and FIT_num? that defines the datatype, should be `250000x1` or something and `cell`

Comment: Thanks a lot Gunther. FIT_txt is a cell of size 248024x1 and FIT_num has the same size but class double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's solve this step by step: I'm assuming `FIT_txt` is a `Nx1` cell array and `sector` is a `Mx1` cell array.

First find the rows in FIT_txt where `sector(ii)` appears in, and also how many times:

```
ii=1;
sector_occurrence = strfind(FIT_txt,sector(ii));
```

This gives you `N` cells for each row of FIT_txt with in each cell the actual location at each row where `sector(ii)` is found. You just need the count per row, so use [numel](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/numel.html) to get just that:

```
cellfun(@numel,sector_occurrence );
```

You can do this for every element of `sector` with a loop or with [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html):

```
sector_occurrence = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(ii) cellfun(@numel,strfind(FIT_txt,sector{ii})),1:numel(sector),'uni',false'));
```

Now you have a NxM matrix. The element at row i and column j tells how many times `sector(j)` occurs in `FIT_txt(i)`.

*reading your comments...
Aah, but if a sector is found, FIT_txt is exactly equal to the sector, which allows you the simplify all the above this with strcmp and arrayfun:

```
sector_occurrence = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(sectorii) strcmp(FIT_txt,sectorii), sector', 'uni',false))
```

Now onto the summation:

It's just a vector product of the occurrence vector with `FIT_num`, and you can get them all in one call by multiplying the `sector_occurrence` matrix with `FIT_num`:

```
sumresult = sector_occurrence'*FIT_num;
```

note the transpose operator `'` because `sector_occurrence` was defined as `NxM`.

### Example

```
>> sector=[{'AB10'} ; {'b'}];
>> FIT_txt=[{'AB10'} ; {'a'} ; {'b'} ; {'ZX5b'} ; {'AB10'} ; {'b'}];
>> FIT_num = (1:6)';

>> sector_occurrence = strfind(FIT_txt,sector(ii))

sector_occurrence =

     1     0
     0     0
     0     1
     0     0
     1     0
     0     1

>> sumresult = sector_occurrence'*FIT_num

sumresult =

     6
     9
```

Of course, it has to be an exact match (which you said it was) `b` won't be equal to `B` and also not to `bb`, only `b`.

### Remark on large data set

`sector_occurrence` is a `logical` array, so it doesn't need that much memory. But when executing the multiplication with `FIT_num`, it gets converted to `float`, which needs 8 times as much space. The end result is a small (in memory) vector, but the intermediary process can melt your pc. You can avoid this by doing the multiplication in a loop:

```
sumresult=NaN(numel(sector),1); %preallocation is a good thing
for ii=1:numel(sector)
    sumresult(ii)=sector_occurrence(:,ii)'*FIT_num;
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that. When I run the first part of the script I am getting following error: "??? Error using ==>
cell.strfind at 35
If any of the input arguments
are cell arrays, the first
must be
a cell array of strings and
the second must be a character
array.".

Comment: can you retry? I forgot to add something (see edit). Btw, you actually just need the two last code lines

Comment: Have tried "sector_occurrence = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(sectorii) strcmp(c,x),sector','uni',false))" - it's not quite working for me. To be honest, I am not understanding the code very well just yet. it doesn't recognise c and x - I have replaces them with FIT_txt and sector (is that correct?), but it's yielding following error: " Error using ==> strcmp
Inputs must be the same size
or either one can be a scalar.".

Comment: oops, 2nd error today :s fixed and tested now. If you don't understand, look up the function in the documentation, test them out piece by piece, they're not standard but also not that difficult.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort. It now doesn't return an error, but the matrix now contains only "0" values for some reason. Also, I need to create multiple of these matrices with larger amounts of data, and I run out of memory. I think I need to find a solution that does not require such large matrices; something along the lines of what I have posted in my original post (the second example) would be better as it requires less cpu and memory; the problem with that example is that I cannot get the Fit_num sum to work.

Comment: if it contains zeros, there wasn't any match, I've added an example ^^

Comment: Thanks Gunther, seems to be working fine - much appreciated :) 

Earlier, I thought of a different approach altogether; it goes something along the lines of this:

`units = zeros(length(sector),1);
    sum = zeros(length(sector),1);
    
    for a = 1:length(sector)
        units(a,1) = sum(strcmp((FIT_txt(:,1)),(sector(a))))
        x = find(strcmp(FIT_txt(:,1),sector(a))==1);
        sum(a,1) = sum(FIT_num(x,1));
    end`    

What do you think about this - does it compare with your solution at all?

Best,

John